# using rEFInd to get around lack of boot screen when using unsupported GPU in Mac Pro

Tags: macos, mac-pro, efi

I am trying to upgrade a 2012 Mac Pro (model 5,1) to Mojave.  I have installed High Sierra and updated bootrom to MP51.0089.B00.  I've got a required "metal capable" graphics card (Sapphire PULSE Radeon RX580), which unfortunately does not support the Startup Manager.  I want access to the Startup Manager, to be able to access recovery partitions and bootable external media.

My plan: rEFInd seems like a good solution to my problem. Before installing the unsupported GPU, if I can get rEFInd to appear as an option in the Startup Manager, I can select it as the default using the control key when selecting the boot option (this *does* work on my machine).  Then once I install the unsupported GPU, the rEFInd main screen will appear on startup and I can select whatever I want, including recovery partitions and external media. (Obviously I must be careful never to change the default in SystemPrefs->StartupDisk, or I'll have to temporarily re-install the old GPU and change the default back to rEFInd !).   Does this sound like a workable plan ?

I've installed rEFInd, with default options, and it does not appear in Startup Manager.   To get it  to appear in Startup Manager, I believe I need to reinstall it with the --usedefault option.   How do I reinstall ?   Do I need to uninstall first (since I first installed it without the usedefault option) ?  Uninstalling looks somewhat problematic.   And what argument do I need to use with --usedefault ?   I've looked at a wiki and a manpage, but am still confused.  When I ran 'mountesp', I got:

```
sudo mountesp
The ESP has been identified as /dev/disk0s1; attempting to mount it....
The ESP is mounted at /Volumes/ESP
```

The only file in that volume is: /Volumes/ESP/EFI/APPLE/EXTENSIONS/Firmware.scap

That's it.  I am out of my depth, and would appreciate help.

Comment: You can temproarily access macOS Recovery by using Command + R which doesn't have anything to do with Startup Manager. You can then use the Startup Disk option to select which disk you would like. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I tried Command+R with the unsupported GPU (the "metal" one needed for Mojave) and the screen stayed black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Removing rEFInd from the EFI partition.

If you use `refind-install` without any options and/or the `--usedefault` option to install rEFInd into the EFI partition (`disk0s1`), then use the following steps to remove rEFInd from this partition.

1. Make sure the EFI partition (`disk0s1`) is unmounted. Use the command given below.

   ```
   diskutil unmount disk0s1
   ```
2. Mount the EFI partition (`disk0s1`). The command is given below.

   ```
   sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
   ```
3. Use the Finder to open the `EFI` folder on the `EFI` volume.
4. If any of the following folders exist in the `EFI` folder, then move each folder to the trash: `BOOT`, `refind` and `tools`

   In other words, if the any of the following folders exist, then the folder should be removed.

   ```
   /Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT
   /Volumes/EFI/EFI/refind
   /Volumes/EFI/EFI/tools
   ```
5. Empty the trash.
6. Use the command given below to unmount the EFI partition.

   ```
   diskutil unmount disk0s1
   ```

### Installing rEFInd to appear in the Mac Startup Manager

> Note: If rEFInd already exists in the EFI partition (`disk0s1`), then the instructions given in this section may fail. You should make sure rEFInd is removed from the EFI partition (`disk0s1`) before proceeding.

The commands to install the current version of rEFInd is given below. You should enter these commands from macOS.

```
sudo $HOME/Downloads/refind-bin-0.12.0/refind-install --usedefault /dev/disk0s1
diskutil unmount disk0s1
```

Below is the output when the above commands were entered using the current version of Catalina (macOS 10.13.6).

[image]

> Note: When testing, I received the error message `sed: -i may not be used with stdin`. This error did not effect the installation of rEFInd other than not unmounting `disk0s1`

The rEFInd Boot Manager should now appear in the Mac Startup Manager with the label `EFI Boot`. Both the icon and label can be customized.

Comment: Thanks.   So no need to un-install what I've already done (when I used the install script with no options) ?

Comment: It complained that the /dev/disk0s1 "resource was busy" so I rebooted into the OSX that was not on the partition where /dev/disk0s1 is.  And then the install seemed to work, until "Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc".   Also complained that refind.conf already existed so it coulnd't copy the sample one to it; I assume that doesn't matter, since I never edited it, unless using --usedefault in the install makes the sample one different somehow.

Comment: Anyhow, it didn't work; rEFInd does not appear in the Startup Manager.

Comment: Seems like it ("Could not set boot device property") could be because of SIP.  I see instructions elsewhere for disabling SIP temporarily (booting into recovery mode) but also that it should no longer be necessary.

Comment: After testing, I determined your previous installation of rEFInd needs to be removed from the EFI partition before installing rEFINd using the `--usedefault` option. I updated my answer.

Comment: rEFInd did not appear in the Mac Startup Manager, because rEFInd already existed in the EFI partition due to a previous install. Your attempt to install did not place the rEFInd files in the the correct locations with the correct names. Therefore, rEFInd could not possible appear in the Mac Startup Manager. I probably should have tested for this possibility before I posted my original answer. I suppose I was in a hurry to get my yard work done outside before curfew and the troops moved in.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Do you think it makes more sense to take the route of creating a small HFS partition and installing there with the --ownhfs option ?  Seems kinda odd to be installing it on the EFI partition of one or the other of my bootable partitions, when this is sort of a "meta" thing (not specific to any of my OSX versions).   I understand this means rEFInd would appear in SystemPrefs->StartupDisk (where I can set it as default simply by selecting it) and NOT in Startup Manager.  Might this be a better approach ?

Comment: If you create a small HFS partition and install there with the `--ownhfs` option, then rEFInd will appear in ***both*** the Mac Startup Manager and Startup Disk pane of macOS System Preferences. You will ***not*** be able to select rEFInd from the Startup Disk pane of macOS System Preferences.

Comment: Ok, so nothing is gained over doing it with --usedefault.   Sorry you've tried to tell me this before, and I just can't quite grok it; this stuff is intensely confusing to me.

Comment: This page https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html seems to conflict with what you're saying "If, however, you installed rEFInd by using the --ownhfs option to refind-install, your rEFInd installation volume should show up as an option in the Startup Disk utility. You should be able to click on it and then click Restart."

Comment: Ok, I posted a question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1556748/can-not-select-refind-from-macos-system-preferences). I used superuser because @RodSmith has never answered a question here at Ask Different.

Comment: I deleted the posted question, because I asked a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/986625/building-boot-caches-on-boot-helper-partition-failed-error-selecting-refind) almost 5 years ago. This question was answered by Rod Smith. Did you try to do this? If so, where you successful? If rEFInd could be selected from the Startup Pane since Yosemite, I was unaware. However, you cannot using the current version of macOS (Mojave).

Comment: No, I haven't tried anything new - was waiting to see if Rod answered.  So cannot using Mojave ?  I'm starting to think the only good solution is to toggle between HighSierra and Mojave using SystemPrefs->StartupDisk, and if I ever need recovery partitions or external media, stick the old GPU back in.   Kind of a hassle, but this rEFInd stuff is confusing the heck out of me.   But maybe I should try reinstalling with proper deletion as you outline above, and see if I can get rEFInd to come up in the Startup Manager.

Comment: I did try to post a question on the [Discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/discussion/) page for rEFInd at SourceForge. Unfortunately, the question never made it passed moderation. Other questions have been posted there and accepted since my post. Therefore, I would assume there will be no further answers from Rod Smith or anyone else associated with rEFInd.

Comment: Didn't pass moderation ?!? WTF ?   I assume you didn't insult him or use hate speech.   That is very odd.

Comment: I suppose the question was not about rEFInd itself, but rather about the documentation published by Rod Smith. Asking a question about a feature which may have not worked for the past 4 and 1/2 years would not be appropriate. The question may have been rejected based on this alone. I suspect the documentation you referenced was written before El Capitan was released and is correct as long as OS X is Yosemite or older.

Comment: I guess to me, more appropriate would've been if they'd said (if it was indeed the case) that the feature doesn't work post-ElCap - especially given the documentation was out-of-date.  Anyhow, thanks again for your help.  I shall set aside the approach of trying to select rEFInd via SystemPrefs->StartupDisk, and go back to the StartupManager approach.

Comment: I have gotten rEFInd to appear in the Startup Manager (hold option key on startup) and am able to select it as the default, by holding the control key when I select it from the Startup Manager.   And now, every time I startup the computer, I am brought to rEFInd (without doing anything on startup); which is exactly what needs to happen, since the Startup Manager will not work after I install the new GPU required for Mojave.  So far, so good.

Comment: Unfortunately, my various bootable partitions no longer appear in the rEFInd menu; I only see one of them (an old one), and the options to shutdown, manage "hidden keys", etc.

Comment: But they still do appear in the Startup Manager (if I hold down the option key on startup).

Comment: Pressing the 'escape' key caused all my bootable paritions to appear.   So I need to edit the refind.conf file and change scan_delay to a non-zero value.